# get_posts - get all posts by array of author

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

I have a case like below.

[image]

Confused how to use the wpQuery to achieve this

This is for a single user. Not sure how can i pass the array.

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();                      

$args = array(
    'author'        =>  $current_user->ID, 
    'orderby'       =>  'random',
    'post_per_page' => '1',
    'order'         =>  'ASC' 
    );

$current_user_posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `author__in` not `author` as a query parameter.

```
$authors = [ 1, 2, 3, ];

$current_user_posts = get_posts( [
    'author__in'    =>  $authors, 
    'orderby'       =>  'random',
    'post_per_page' => '1',
    'order'         =>  'ASC' 
] );
```